# DCEVM installation unsuccessful - JVM_CopySwapMemory error (not found in jvm.dll)

Tags: java, hotswap, dcevm

I am using Idea with JDK1.8.0_201 and DCEVM-8u181-installer-build2. The installer seems to modify JDK without errors but when I try to run java -version or java -version -XXaltjvm=dcevm a system error pops up in my native language (I am using localised Win 7). The translation would be roughly "Entry point of procedure JVM_CopySwapMemory was not found in dynamically joined library jvm.dll".

What is the problem? Am I using incompatible versions of DCEVM and Java or does the problem lie elsewhere?